# Instagram browser does not handle ICS links

Tags: calendar, instagram, icalendar

I have a link to the ICS calendar: [See here](http://api.agafonova.ru.com/calendar.php?calendar=ics&event=7160:favorite-thing&time=1536253200000)

Every browser handles it properly (download file on Desktop and open Calendar app on iPhone), except Instagram in-app browser - when you open this link in Instagram (like from Direct Messages), it just shows file content.

How do I force the Instagram app to open Calendar app for this type of links?

Here is part of PHP code I use to generate this file:

```
    $calendar_string = [];
    $calendar_string[] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "VERSION:2.0\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "PRODID:-//Veronika Agafonova//NONSGML Veronika Agafonova//EN\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "METHOD:REQUEST\n"; // requied by Outlook
    $calendar_string[] = "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-example.com\n"; // required by Outlok
    $calendar_string[] = "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n"; // required by Outlook
    $calendar_string[] = "DTSTART:$date_start\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "DTEND:$date_end\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "SUMMARY:$title\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "DESCRIPTION:$details\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "END:VEVENT\n";
    $calendar_string[] = "END:VCALENDAR\n";

    header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calendar.ics");
    header("Content-Length: ". strlen(implode("", $calendar_string)).";");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Connection: close");

    echo implode("", $calendar_string);
```

Comment: I'm 5 years late, but did you ever find a solution for this?